# How to validate dynamically generated drop down list by ajax using jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Actually i have a drop down list with parent categories, upon select the parent category, a new drop down list dynamically displaying with sub categories using ajax in the div tag, now i want to validate the subcategory drop down list using jquery.

Comment: What do you mean by "validate"? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to access the value of that dropdown, use

```
$('#subdropdownid').val()
```

And do the necessary actions.

Could you please be more specific about what do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you are evaluating the  dynamically generated drop down, you will need to use the live function - http://api.jquery.com/live/